# Including <map> causes compilation error with g++ 4.6.2

Tags: c++, dictionary, g++, mingw

I'm getting a strange compilation error, that i cannot explain. Following code is a minimal example, getting me this error:

```
#include <map>
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, I'm gettin an error because of including the map-header file:

```
p:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:109:15: error: 'map' is not a template
p:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:162:48: error: only declarations of constructors can be 'explicit'
p:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:172:17: error: 'map' does not name a type
p:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:252:7: error: 'map' does not name a type
p:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:693:12: error: 'map' is not a type
p:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:856:26: error: 'map<_K1, _T1, _C1, _A1>' does not name a type
p:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:857:12: error: 'map<_K1, _T1, _C1, _A1>' does not name a type
...
```

This goes on and on (100s of such errors). I don't have a problem with including other c++ headers (like string, vector etc).

I've tried finding something about this via google, without success. Does anyone have an idea what can be the cause for a problem like this?

If it helps: i'm using Windows 7, and running 'g++ -v' outputs:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=p:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.2/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --enable-shared --enable-libgomp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version: 4.6.2 (GCC)
```

Comment: Did you use std namespace?

Comment: This sounds much like header file corruption. The first line with an error might have some extraneous characters.

Comment: Definitely looks like a file corruption, wipe and reinstall your gcc/mingw installation.